# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer , the costhistory has to be a float already

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

here cost_history is supposed to be a float array, idk what the error means, help

Comment: Please see [ask], which specifically says not to post screenshots of code, data, error messages...

Comment: The `np.zeros` argument is supposed to be an integer (or tuple of integers).  `range` will also have this requirement.  What is `iters`; how is it created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states that `iters` is not an int. This seems to be because you're passing the arguments in a different order than expected. Notice the function definition:

```
def bgd(X, y, w, iters, lamb, alpha):
```

And now, checkout the variable names you provide to call the function:

```
bgd(X, y, w, alpha, iters, lamb)
```

You probably want to change your function call to:

```
bgd(X, y, w, iters, lamb, alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up alpha and iters.  Your definition and calling mixed up. so np.zeros is getting alpha which is float instead of iters.